# android.content.res.resources notfoundexception $android.content.res.resources notfoundexception $ string resource id #0x1

Tags: android

Iam selecting multiple contacts using CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView wtih reference of [`this`](https://github.com/krishnalalstha/Spannable) in that code selecting multiple contacts but i want to show what are the numbers are selected on toast message. when button is clicked for that i modified that code
in `main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.krishna.widget.CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText" 
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and i added this field in `CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView.java`

```
public HashMap<String, String> con=new HashMap<String, String>();
```

for saving contact numbers in this `Hashmap`

I modified in

```
CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView.java


public void init(Context context){


....

this.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
    
...
con.put(contact.num.toString(), contact.contactName.toString());
}
});
       
    }
and i modified 
MainActivity.java
```

like this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    Button b1;
    private CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView phoneNum;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        phoneNum = (CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView)
                findViewById(R.id.editText);
        ContactPickerAdapter contactPickerAdapter = new ContactPickerAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, SmsUtil.getContacts(
                    this, false));
        phoneNum.setAdapter(contactPickerAdapter);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        //phoneNum.addTextChangedListener((TextWatcher));
        }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView phoneNum=(CustomMultiAutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        HashMap<String, String> map=(HashMap<String, String>)phoneNum.con;
        
        try{
            
            

            Toast.makeText(this, map.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("eee",e.toString());
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    
    }
```

now arter execution i selected one contact after that if iam pressing button i am `unable to get map size()`
there iam getting `android.content.res.resources$notfoundexception string resource id #0x1`
Can i know why this error is comming. how to get selected contact information in main activity   any body help me to solve this problem

Comment: You should include your error log.

Comment: i included . iam getting error when accessing map.size() in the button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, map.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

To this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(map.size()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

There are 2 versions of `Toast.makeText`. In one, the second parameter is a String, in the other it's an int resource id.

You are passing it an int `map.size()` and it thinks it's a resource id, which it cannot find. Therefore you are getting `android.content.res.resources.notfoundexception`

Comment: ok it is working can i know how get selected contacts i.e. name and contact number in that map

Comment: when you got right answer, don't forget to up vote the answer]

Comment: i can give up vote because my reputation is low i can give after 15 only